# Wanted: Swift Class of fixed memory as array

Tags: arrays, sorting, generics, memory, shared-libraries

I need a class, which allocates a memory block for generic Type . It should offer all usual features like indexing, adding, sort etc. But in contrast to the build in functionality, there should be no dynamic memory allocation for each element. So it is a relatively static array. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I ask if there is already something as a library or an addin etc. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```swift
    class StaticArray<T> {
    private var data: [T]
    private let capacity: Int
    
    init(capacity: Int) {
        self.capacity = capacity
        data = Array<T>(repeating: nil, count: capacity)
    }
    
    subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        get {
            return data[index]
        }
        set {
            data[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func append(_ value: T) {
        // Check if array is full before appending
        guard data.count < capacity else {
            return
        }
        data.append(value)
    }
    
    func sort() {
        data.sort()
    }
}
```